# Removing legend on charts with chart.js v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, chart.js2

I'm making a homepage using, Bootstrap, JQuery and Chart.js (v2). I had my implementation working using v1, but recently just got into Bower and downloaded v2 using that.

I'm making a grid of 4 columns each containing a pie chart, however the scaling in v2 is sort of confusing for me to get working. I want the charts to be responsive so they scale properly with the smaller devices such as tablets and smartphones, and one of my problems is getting rid of the legend of the charts as well as the hover information when hovering the mouse over the sections of my chart.

## index.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

## functions.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = $("#chart1");
    var data = {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            data: [10, 10],
            backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#FDB45C"],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF5A5E", "#FFC870"]
        }]
    };

    var chart1 = new Chart(canvas, {
        type: "pie",
        data: data,
    });
});
```

If I remove the empty "labels" field the chart doesn't work anymore. And by the looks of it there is a small spacing at the top of the chart which could indicate that the headers are written, but they are just empty strings.

Does anyone have an idea of how to remove the legend, and the hover description? I simply can't get my head around how this is used

I will get my hands around a jsfiddle as soon as I get time!

EDIT: Link to the docs: https://nnnick.github.io/Chart.js/docs-v2/#getting-started

Answer (score 339, accepted):

## From chart.js version 2.x backwards:

The options object can be added to the chart when the new Chart object is created.

```
var chart1 = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: "pie",
    data: data,
    options: {
         legend: {
            display: false
         },
         tooltips: {
            enabled: false
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was using react and this hwo to do in react way..<Doughnut data={data} options={{ legend: false}} />

Comment: Be careful there is also global property that can be accessed within object.
<Doughnut data={data} legend= {display: false} />
This one set it for all charts instead just one.

Comment: Chart.js v3 has legend configuration under `options.plugins.legend.display` now.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

Comment: I think this is not a good approach. bcz this yaxes and xaxes and other stuff squeezing

Answer (score 126):

## From chart.js version 3.x onwards:

[legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/configuration/legend.html), [title](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/configuration/title.html) and [tooltip](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/configuration/tooltip.html) namespaces are moved from options to `options.plugins`.

```
var chart1 = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: "pie",
    data: data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: After trying 20 different things, which did not work. As of Sep 2021, this works.

Comment: As of 2023, for anyone using ChartJS v3.x or v4.x, this is the correct answer! 

FWIW if there is a highly rated answer on SO about ChartJS that involves an options setting, but it doesn't seem to work for you, then as a first port of call try nesting that setting inside options: { **plugins**: {},}. This may fix your issue (it has for me on several occasions!)

Answer (score 49):

You can change default options by using `Chart.defaults.global` in your javascript file. So you want to change legend and tooltip options.

### Remove legend

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
```

### Remove Tooltip

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/cmlonder/pen/grjRLZ) is a working fiddler.

Comment: Cool. I didn't how to use those functions as I didn't know that I could just write those commands in my Javascript.

Answer (score 10):

Modifying Ishan's answer

If you are using react like me,

```
const data = {
...
}

const options = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
};


<Bar data={data} options={options} />
```

Answer (score 4):

For me this didn't work:

> legend: { display: false }

But this works great, thank you.

> plugins: {
> legend: {
> display: false,
> },
> }

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chartjs version 2.x
Then adding simply:

```
legend: {
  display: false,
},
```

But if you're using chart.js version 3.x or above, then all these properties have been moved into elements so simply add over there

```
elements: {
  line: {
    borderWidth: 0.4,
  },
  point: {
    radius: 0,
    hitRadius: 10,
    hoverRadius: 4,
    hoverBorderWidth: 3,
  },
  legend: {
    display: false,
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add that line 
legend: {
    display: false
        }

Comment: how is this answer different form other answers?

Answer (score 0):

For people using Chart JS 4+ it can be configured via the options like this:

```
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
```