# How to disable the legends in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I'm trying to style a chart using chart.js but I can't figure out how to disable the legends. At the same time I want to use the generateLegend() to style the legends somewhere else on the page. So I just want to disable the legends inside the canvas element. Can you guys help me?

Here's my code:

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<div id="legendq3"></div>

<script> 
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

    var data = {
        labels: [
            "Red",
            "Green",
            "Yellow"
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [300, 50, 100],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56"
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56"
                ]
            }]
    };

    var options = {
         legendTemplate :'<ul>'
                        +'<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>'
                        +'</li>'
                        +'<span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span>'
                        +'<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><%= datasets[i].label %><% } %>'
                        +'</li>'
                        +'</ul>'
         
    }

    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: data,
        options: options
    });

    document.getElementById('legendq3').innerHTML = myDoughnutChart.generateLegend();
</script>
```

Comment: I believe `Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;` will globally display a legend from displaying.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me where specifically in my code I should insert this

Comment: I believe `Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;` will globally disable a legend from displaying placed at the start of your script since this will globally disable legends for all charts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing legend on charts with chart.js v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749509/removing-legend-on-charts-with-chart-js-v2)

Answer (score 12):

Adding this to the `options` worked for me:

```
plugins: {
    legend: false,
}
```

src: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Answer (score 6):

This probably is late for the person who originated the question. But, I still put the solution that worked for me without much hassle for the next guys who might encounter the same problem. Just pass display property false value to both legend & labels properties, like bellow.

```
options: {
  legend: {
    display: false,
      labels: {
        display: false
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The global options for the chart legend is defined in Chart.defaults.global.legend

Put this in your code (after you declare the chart):

```
myDoughnutChart.defaults.global.legend.display = false
```

Comment: Actually it makes the legends that I created with myDoughnutChart.generateLegend(); I actually want the original legends to disappear, i.e. the one with the block of colors.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html?h=legend), the below property can be added to the options object to hide the legend:

```
var chart = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the legend option to 'none'

```html
{ legend: 'none' }
```

Source : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart