# Removing legend from chart.js Radar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, radar-chart

I am using the Radar chart from  Chart.js and I want to hide the legend(label) I did this:

```
new Chart("myChart", {
            type: "radar",
            data: data,
            options: {
                legend:{
                    display: false,
                },
               }
          });
```

But is not working for some reasons also checked those:
[Removing legend on charts with chart.js v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749509/removing-legend-on-charts-with-chart-js-v2)
[Removing legend on charts with chart.js v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749509/removing-legend-on-charts-with-chart-js-v2)
I'm doing the same but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the migration guide (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html#specific-changes) the `legend` has been moved to the `plugins` namespace so you will need to put it like so:

```js
new Chart("myChart", {
    type: "radar",
    data: data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
        }
    }
});
```