# How to remove Label from charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using charts.js to create a charts for my website.
I am unable the remove the legend from the chart.
[image]

I did not found the solution. This is the first time I am using charts.js library.

code:

```
const ctx1 = document.getElementById('yearWise').getContext('2d');
const yearWise = new Chart(ctx1, {
type: 'bar',
plugins: [ChartDataLabels],

data: {
    legend: 'options',
    labels: ['2018-19','2019-20','2020-21','2021-22'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [90,400,5245,5122],
        backgroundColor: [
            // 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
            'rgba(70, 132, 238, 0.5)',
        ],
        borderColor: [
            // 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(70, 132, 238, 1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    legend: {
        display: false,
     },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Programs Conducted - Year Wise',
      },
      datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'end',
          labels: {
            value: {
              color: 'rgba(70, 132, 238, 1)'
            }
          }
      },          
    },
}
```

});
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look through this https://stackoverflow.com/q/36749509/10882535

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing legend on charts with chart.js v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749509/removing-legend-on-charts-with-chart-js-v2)

Comment: No, I tried this method but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

you can simply set `legend.display` to false.

```
options: {
  plugin: {
    legend: {
        display: false,
    }
  }
}
```

You can try it here
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonj2xn23w?file=/src/index.js